# Why I can not overload this method?

Tags: java, overloading

Here is the code:

```
public class Test {    
    private static void print(List<Plant> plants) {
        
    }

    private static void print(List<Animal> animals) {

    }
}


class Animal {

}

class Plant {
   
}
```

When I want to overload `print` method in Test class for Animal and Plant lists, the compiler says that "both methods have same erasure". When I research "method erasure", I could not relate it to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Because both `List<Plant>` and `List<Animal>` are `List` (raw type) using type erasure, so compiler sees 2 `print` methods are identical.